# java application take a while to start with hsqldb server

Tags: java, hsqldb, server

so i try this code :

```
Connection conn;
try {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.setDatabaseName(0, "mydbname");

    server.setDatabasePath(0, "file:C:/path/testdb;user=root;password=pass");
    server.start();
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydbname.0");
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pas encore !!!");
}
```

my problem is with that code my application take a while to start , if they start, because sometimes they dont start withe any exceptions.

please help me

Comment: How long is "a while"? And how much time would be ok for your requirements?

Comment: how can i calculate it...something like more 1 minute ... and what about the time whene it don't work withe this same code !!!

Comment: I think that your application is slow because you create the server in the source code. Why did you use the Server class to start the server ? You can use the command line or the in memory hsqldb which will be faster or if you want a server and is in Servlet environnement, start it at web server start (in web.xml). From HSQL documentation: The command line is "the preferred way of running a database server and the fastest one."

Comment: the server is opned in 600ms , look at this :

Comment: ok ill try the commande line and check the difference thanks

Comment: from eclipse consolle :i have this : Startup sequence completed in 687 ms.

Comment: so the server is created in a accepted time but the connection to the server  is too slow so i guess this is the problem...first ill try the commande line